# Getting Babel error when compiling build with Create React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, create-react-app

For my web app I used Create React App to build it with the typescript template. I am about ready to deploy but I am unable to create a production build with `npm run build`. Because of the following Babel error:

```
src/constants/{file-name}.js
  Line 0:  Parsing error: You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module configuration file, which is only supported when running Babel asynchronously
```

This happens for every file I use to store constant values which are used across my web app. I have tried a lot of things such as refactoring them into .json files and changing my babel config file to .cjs but nothing seems to work. I don't really get why Babel has such a problem with me using exported values from other files since I use functions from other files.

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    return {
      plugins: ['macros'],
    }
  }
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@metamask/sdk": "^0.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.4",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.9.2",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.34",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.8",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "emoji-picker-react": "^4.4.11",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "ethers": "^6.6.7",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "prompt-sync": "^4.2.0",
    "rate-limiter-flexible": "^2.4.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.10",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "web3": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "typescript": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "prisma": "^5.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```